# problem building matrix through use of a loop

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var shuffle = function() {
    var set = [];
    var waiter = [];
    var suitset = ["Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds","Spades"];
    for (var r = 1;r <= 13;r++) {
        for (var s = 0;s < suitset.length;s++) {
            card = [];
            var cardeval = evalcard(r); //This is an input from another function
            card.push(cardeval[0]);
            card.push(suitset[s]);
            card.push(cardeval[1]);
            waiter.push(card);
        }
    }
    while (waiter.length) { //This is what randomizes the deck aka shuffles
        set.push(waiter.splice(Math.random() * waiter.length,1));
    }

    return set;
};
```

I'm trying to build a matrix of cards (I'm using matrix here as an array of arrays). There will be 52 arrays of card arrays, each of which holds a card number, suit, and value. But after I call the function, `card` returns as a string and not an array, even though it is defined with array brackers `[]`. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/LuUT5/12/)**

```
function evalcard() { return [1,2]}

    var shuffle = function() {
        var set = [];
        var waiter = [];
        var suitset = ["Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds","Spades"];

        for (var r = 1;r <= 13;r++) {
            for (var s = 0;s < suitset.length;s++) {
                var card = {},
                    cardeval = evalcard(r); 

                card.num = cardeval[0];
                card.suite = suitset[s];
                card.val = cardeval[1];

                waiter.push(card);
            }
        }

        while (waiter.length) { //This is what randomizes the deck aka shuffles
            var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (waiter.length-1));
            set.push(waiter[randomNum]);
            waiter.splice(randomNum ,1)
        }
        return set;
    };

    var test = shuffle();
    console.log(test);
    alert(test[0].suite);
```

Made the cards into objects, and just passed them into an array instead just for easier accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LuUT5/

```
function evalcard() { return [1,2]}
var shuffle = function() {
    var set = [];
    var waiter = [];
    var suitset = ["Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds","Spades"];
    for (var r = 1;r <= 13;r++) {
        for (var s = 0;s < suitset.length;s++) {
            card = [];
            var cardeval = evalcard(r); //This is an input from another function
            waiter.push([cardeval[0],suitset[s],cardeval[1]]);
        }
    }
    while (waiter.length) { //This is what randomizes the deck aka shuffles
        var x = waiter.splice(Math.random() * waiter.length,1);
        set.push(x);
    }
    return set;
};
var deck = shuffle()[0];
alert(deck[0][1])
```

Comment: @mplungjan--no, `shuffle()[1]` returns (number,suit,value) as a string... if you try calling `shuffle()[1][1]` it will return undefined.

Maybe this is a syntax problem? is `matrix()[n][n]` the proper way to call arrays within arrays?